# can i get a different response from postman example

Tags: postman

let's me explain 
i'm using mock server in post man for testing login post

so i set header to [x-api-key : {{postman-api-key}} //(i already got my api key from postman)

and I set Body request and response like this

[image]

my question is : If i post wrong password from body request can i set body response to show (error ,Password incorrect) form other example it's possible?

There is any To samples for me?

Comment: Can you explain clearly? That depends on how you pass JSON response

Comment: If I understand what you wanna do correctly, you can add `console.log('Error: password incorrect')` to see the error in console. You cannot make Postman display custom response body, obviously